# MonetDB auto-backup mechanic problem

Tags: linux, backup, restore

I'm trying to set up mechanism that will automatically create database backup.
The idea is to create a script that will be executed by crontab. Seems easy but I'm struggling with the following problems:

- I cannot use `msqldump`, because it needs password input from the user;
- I've tried physical copy, but after removing database or dbfarm and restoring them, monetdb and monetdbd couldn't start "restored" database and dbfarm;

Can I bypass above problems and/or are there other solutions?

Comment: presumably you've seen the MonetDB page about doing a physical file copy?  https://www.monetdb.org/Documentation/UserGuide/FastDumpRestore

Answer (score 1):

1. Create .monetdb file in the home directory as below:

   ```
   cat << EOF > $HOME/.monetdb
   user=monetdb
   password=monetdb
   EOF
   ```
2. Replace the above content with your monetdb username and password.
3. Change the file permission to prevent other user from reading it [optional]
4. Run:

   ```
   export msqldump=$HOME/.monetdb
   echo 'export msqldump=$HOME/.monetdb' >> $HOME/.bashrc
   ```

After making above changes, I have ran the below mysqldump command, it doesn't ask user to input password.

```
mysqldump -d[database-name] > [sql_dump_backup_path]
```

Source :[How to setup mysqldump without password in cronjob](http://www.techiecorner.com/1619/how-to-setup-mysqldump-without-password-in-cronjob/)